# Nginx + Gunicorn POST request error

Tags: django, post, nginx, http-post, gunicorn

Im using nginx as a proxy for a django application that uses gunicorn, the problem is that at some point I receive a POST request from another site.

The problem seems to be that nginx does not redirect the POST request properly to the gunicorn daemon.

What can I do to fix this, what I need is to be able to send the POST request as it arrives to the gunicorn daemor for my django app to process it... thank you...

This is my nginx conf

```
server {

    server_name www.rinconcolombia.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/rinconcolombia.log;

    location / {
        ssi on;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
        root /home/rincon/sites/rinconcolombia/checkouts/rinconcolombia/;
    }

    location /static/admin_media/ {
                autoindex on;
        root /home/rincon/sites/rinconcolombia/checkouts/rinconcolombia/;
    }

}

server {
    server_name www.rinconcolombia.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.rinconcolombia.com$1;
}
```

UPDATE The app sending the POST is receiving a BAD REQUEST error... if I manually make a POST with resty or curl It does pass the post message to my server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nginx configuration is slightly wrong as you're missing the fail_timeout bits. See here for the gunicorn/nginx example: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf

Specifically lines 58 and 115.

If that doesn't help do you get anything in the nginx error.log?

Comment: Aparently the other app was sending bad requests... still thank you for your answer Ill have to check my nginx configuration to avoid problems in the future.